# query for find the counter that does not follow the order

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table holding transaction dates and counter like this

| NO CARD | DATE | COUNTER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1377370849 | 2022/11/13 11:14:12 | 76 |
| 1377370849 | 2022/11/13 11:14:33 | 77 |
| 1377370849 | 2022/11/13 11:14:45 | 80 |
| 1377370849 | 2022/11/13 11:14:55 | 85 |
| 1377370849 | 2022/11/13 11:24:05 | 86 |
| 1377370849 | 2022/11/13 11:24:11 | 87 |
| 1377370849 | 2022/11/13 11:24:12 | 88 |
| 1377370849 | 2022/11/13 11:24:13 | **12** |
| 1377370849 | 2022/11/13 11:34:10 | 89 |
| 1377370849 | 2022/11/13 11:44:01 | 90 |
| 1377370849 | 2022/11/13 11:44:05 | 91 |
| 1377370849 | 2022/11/13 11:44:11 | 92 |
| 1377370849 | 2022/11/13 11:54:22 | **120** |
| 1377370849 | 2022/11/13 11:54:26 | 93 |
| 1377370849 | 2022/11/13 11:54:32 | 99 |
| 1377370849 | 2022/11/13 11:54:45 | 100 |

I have to find counter 12 and counter 120. The counter is an incrementing counter, and it becomes 1 again at 250. 
12  => counter incrementing but downs to 12 and become 89 again after 12 
120 => counter jumps to 120 and become 93 after 120

How I can write to SQL Query for this. (Oracle 11)

Comment: 120 becomes 93, btw

Comment: Did you try MATCH_RECOGNIZE?

Comment: AFAIK, Oracle11 does not provide this, it was introduced in Oracle12c.

Comment: Oracle version is 11.2. I guess MATCH_RECOGNIZE is after 12c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEAD` and `LAG` for that. If I understand correct, your counter is valid when it's between the previous and the next counter.
This can be verified like that:

```
WITH orderedData AS
(SELECT no_card, yourdate, counter,
LAG(counter, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY yourdate) AS counter_prev,
LEAD(counter, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY yourdate) AS counter_next
FROM yourtable)
SELECT counter FROM orderedData 
WHERE NOT counter BETWEEN counter_prev AND counter_next
AND counter_prev < counter_next;
```

This will return 12 and 120 for your sample data since those two values don't satisfy this condition.

Note: It might be needed to add a `PARTITION BY` card_no and/or date clause to both the `LAG` and `LEAD` part if the counter is separated per card number and/or date. That's not clear from your sample data.

So feel free to extend this query if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The rows

```
WHERE counter NOT BETWEEN 
        CASE WHEN 250 = LAG(counter) OVER(PARTITION BY no_card ORDER BY dat) THEN 0 
        ELSE 
        LAG(counter) OVER(PARTITION BY no_card ORDER BY dat) END 
    AND LEAD(counter) OVER(PARTITION BY no_card ORDER BY dat)
```

Comment: Thanks. 
But Result is
30483. 00000 -  "window  functions are not allowed here"
*Cause:    Window functions are allowed only in the SELECT list of a query.
           And, window function cannot be an argument to another window or group
           function.
*Action:

Comment: Yes, I should have said it's the idea, but for the implementation you have to put the window functions in a sub-query with aliases and the WHERE condition on the surrounding one using the aliases you would put on the LEAD and LAG functions..

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm working over it.